# How to use external AMP in alfresco Maven Project

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to use the alfresco-pdf-toolkit addon in my Alfresco Maven project, is there anyway to include the amp in the pom.xml file of my project?

Comment: Are you using the alfresco sdk in your project ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming your project uses the all-in-one archetype of the Alfresco Maven SDK, you can add an AMP dependency as an overlay.

Go look in the repo pom.xml for an example. You'll see something like:

```
<overlay>
    <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-spp</artifactId>
    <type>amp</type>
</overlay>
```

Which is how the all-in-one project brings in the SPP dependency. You can add additional AMPs below that.

You must have already run "mvn install" for the AMPs you are depending on so that they are installed in your local Maven repo, or they must be available in some other maven repo that your build knows about.

Comment: When all-in-one project is generate it creates also `overlay` folders (both in share and repo fodlers). Are there fodler neccessary?

Comment: Also all-in-one prject contains several overlay section. Does it means, that the order must be sthe following (from up to down): overlay with `${alfresco.groupId}` and `${alfresco.share.artifactId}`, then overlay with current project and only then inmported addon?