# How add alfresco extension to project which is build on alfresco maven sdk?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-maven

Suppos that repo and share module were generated from maven alfresco archetype as described [here](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html#your-first-project). And now it needed to install one of [alvex](https://github.com/ITDSystems/alvex) addons. It is clear that jars/amp can be build from sources, but what to do with this? Where to put they in generated maven project to get them installed in alfresco when `mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war` is executed?

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial assumes two separate maven projects created using the repo archetype and the share archetype, respectively.

If you want to be able to run integration tests with multiple AMPs you may rather use the all-in-one archetype instead.

See [How to use external AMP in alfresco Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847132/how-to-use-external-amp-in-alfresco-maven-project)